# When do we use the term prevalence?

Tags: epidemiology

If I calculate at a given time, the proportion of a disease in a  not representative sample of the population of study ; this proportion is called prevalence? Or just a frequency! 
Is there a specific conditions for use the term of prevalence?

Answer (score 1):

The proportion of people with a disease in a certain sample/population at a particular point in time is the sample/population prevalence. If the sample is representative then the sample prevalence approximates the population prevalence.

Frequency is not used synonymously with prevalence in epidemiology in my experience, but can often be used to describe event counts.

The prevalence is dependent on the incidence (the rate at which people newly develop the disease), the survival function (the proportion of people who get the disease and survive to a certain time), and in some cases the recovery rate (the rate at which people with the disease recover from it). In some cases (e.g., for hereditary conditions) the incidence is equal to the prevalence in the birth cohort and there is no recovery rate.

Please feel free to comment and/or update your question if you want more details.

Comment: In your opinion, I can use the term prevalence even if I do not respect the sampling methods known?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. It's okay if you're sampling from a subpopulation but you still need to sample in an unbiased way. Can you give more details?

Comment: My concern is the terminology, can I use the term prevalence of a disease or a phenomenon, only if the sample is unbiased, while respecting the sampling method known?
if the sample is drawn without respect for these methods, here I have a humble opinion:
I use the term frequency (x/∑x ) of the disease or phenomenon (I do not consider the term frequency, as synonymous with prevalence)

Help me to understand

Comment: I wouldn't use the term prevalence if the sample was biased. Frequency would be acceptable, but I don't know why you would be studying a biased sample?

Comment: No! I will not use a biased sample. Only you know that there are some non-probabilistic sampling methods, that does not give a representative sample of the study population or in some cases gives a biased sample.

Comment: Then I would call it the sample prevalence and highlight that there is a risk of bias. Hope that helps.